# How to join and filter 2 relations by columns in Pig?

Tags: apache-pig

I'm a novice to Pig script, and trying to modify some existing pig script to extract some data from log files.

E.g. I have 2 log files, one with the schema as:

```
message Class {
    message Student {
        optional int32 uid = 1;
        optional string name = 2;
    }
    optional int32 cid = 1;
    repeated Student students = 2;
}
```

After loading, I think a bag (say, bag1) is created (correct me if I'm wrong):

```
bag1:
{
(uid1, {(cid11, name11), (cid12, name12), (cid13, name13), ...}),
(uid2, {(cid21, name21), (cid22, name22), (cid23, name23), ...}),
...
}
```

And another log file is simple, the resulting bag (bag2) is like this.

```
bag2:
{
(name11),
(name13),
(name22),
...
}
```

What I want is, get all the rows from bag1 if any name in bag2 is contained inside the row, like:

```
result bag:
{
(uid1, (name11, name13)),
(uid2, (name22)),
}
```

I think I'll need to do some join/filter on these 2 bags, but don't know how.
I tried a script snippet like below, but it's even not a valid script.

```
res = FOREACH bag1 {
        names = FOREACH students GENERATE name;
        xnames = JOIN names by name, bag2 by name;
        GENERATE cid, xnames;
};
FILTER res BY not IsEmpty(xnames);
```

So could anyone pls. give me some help on the script?

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to use `JOIN` inside a nested `FOREACH`, you can try flattening your tuple and then join it  with the second table:

```sql
bag1_flat = FOREACH bag1 GENERATE $0 AS uid, FLATTEN($1);
bag1_flat = FOREACH bag1_flat GENERATE uid, $2 AS name;
```

An inner join, will filter the lines :

```sql
bag12 = JOIN bag1_flat by name, bag2 by $0;
bag12 = FOREACH bag12 GENERATE bag1_flat::uid AS uid, bag1_flat::name AS name;
```

Finally, group by uid you won't get tuples though as they cannot be different sizes, you'll get bags:

```sql
bag12_group = GROUP bag12 BY uid;
res = FOREACH bag12_group GENERATE group AS uid, bag12.name AS names;
```